# Delete rows according to condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Using as key columns 1 and 2, i want to delete all rows which the value increments by one.

input

```
1000 1001 140
1000 1002 140
1000 1003 140
1000 1004 140
1000 1005 140
1000 1006 140
1000 1201 140
1000 1202 140
1000 1203 140
1000 1204 140
1000 1205 140
2000 1002 140
2000 1003 140
2000 1004 140
2000 1005 140
2000 1006 140
```

output desired

```
1000 1001 140
1000 1006 140
1000 1201 140
1000 1205 140
2000 1002 140
2000 1006 140
```

I have tried

```
awk '{if (a[$1] < $2)a[$1]=$2;}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i];}}' <file>
```

But for some reason, it keeps only the maximum value.

Comment: You will get a much more friendly reception and much better help here if you show what code you have tried so far and describe what problems you were having with it. Without code, your question looks like a request for free consulting and many people don't like that.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: i have tried awk '{if (a[$1] < $2)a[$1]=$2;}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i];}}' file but it keeps only the max value. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem statement doesn't describe your output.  You want to print the first and last row of each contiguous range.  Like this:

```
$ awk '$1 > A || $2 > B + 1 {
   if(row){print row}; print} 
   {A=$1; B=$2; row=$0} 
   END {print}' dat

1000 1001 140
1000 1006 140
1000 1201 140
1000 1205 140
2000 1002 140
2000 1006 140
```

The basic problem is just to determine if a line is only 1 more than the prior one.  The only way to do that is to have both lines to compare.  By storing the value of each line as it's read, you can compare the current line to the prior one.

Comment: it works perfect and that was exactly the output needed, thanks